# Posting data into Firebase - with post request - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some posts into Firebase posts.json file that I have manually entered, that look like below, post1, post2...

[image: Text]

When I am entering new data - formData object into Firebase with post request like this:

```
const submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const err = validate();
        if(err === false) {
            setFormData(formData)
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({formData})
            };
            fetch('https://blog-d8b04-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/posts.json', requestOptions)
                .then(response => setLoading(true))
                .then(data => setLoading(false));
        }

        }
```

I'm getting post like this, with unique keys as names that is generating firebase, and below formData.
[image: Text]
But I want they to be the same format like posts I have entered manually into firebase(posts1, post2).
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

A JSON literal `{ formData }` is actually shorthand for `{ formData: formData }`, which explains the format you end up with.

You're looking for:

```
body: JSON.stringify(formData)
```

So without the `{}` around `formData`.